# XMLHttpRequest responseType = "json" giving error SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am having trouble setting the XHR responseType to "json".  It works fine if I leave it an empty string `xml.responseType = "";` but when I set it to "json" I get the console error message SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12.

The .js file:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("GET", "test.php", true);
xml.responseType = "json";
xml.send();
```

The .php file:

```
<?php
$foo = "{\"key1\":\"val1\", \"key2\":\"val2\"}";
echo $foo;
?>
```

Not sure what's going on.. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok.. after further testing, it will accept all of the values mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) ("document", "blob", "arraybuffer", "text", "") EXCEPT for "json".  I tried it on Chrome 17 and Safari 5.1

Comment: Also remember, when outputing information from a server put a proper content mime type in the return.  header("Content-Type: application/json"); should fix the issue.  Also, you should be using json_encode instead of crafting the json yourself.  print json_encode(array("key1" => "val1", "key2" => "val2"));

Comment: As of March 2014, responseType = "json" is supported in latest Chrome and Firefox as well as Opera.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`responseType` property for `XMLHttpRequest` object is added in its new variant [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) and which is included in `HTML 5`, i am not sure all browsers support this method so it could be possible that you are using a browser which doesn't implement that method

instead of using `responseType` you can use following code to get data in desired format

```
 var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xml.open("GET", "test.php", true);

 xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xml.readyState != 4)  { return; }

   var serverResponse = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
 };

 xml.send(null);
```

Comment: or use eval(xml.responseText) to go for sure

Comment: i would not recommend using eval, because doing eval on user returned data is not safe, if you want to make sure that this will work even if browser natively doesn't support JSON parsing then you can use library like this http://www.json.org/js.html, but thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: You can also surround the `JSON.parse` call in a `try-catch` block in order to see whether the `responseText` property was properly parsed as valid JSON.

Comment: Also to note, the JSON.parse() is insanely more lightweight than eval() as well because it doesn't have to worry about functions and actually executing code.  JSON.parse() combined with JSON.stringify() are incredibly invaluable tools.

Comment: exact, on IE don't use xhr.responseType = 'json'; and parse yourself the response var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

Answer (score 8):

The JSON responseType is not implemented in the WebKit.
http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/8107e50e4207eb5a/a5d2c31247feae56?lnk=raot

Update 2016-01-03:
As could be expected, WebKit has implemented this feature in the meantime.

Comment: JSON response type has been implemented in Chromium recently: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=156290

Comment: This feature was released with Chrome 31 in Nov 2013.