# XMLHttpRequest Response Type & JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple PHP script which returns a simple JSON response:

```
$data=array('a'=>'apple');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode(array($date));
```

Using JavaScript, I try to read the data:

```
var url='…';
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, true);
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(this.readyState==4) {
        alert(this.responseText);
        alert(this.responseType);
    }
};
```

The code works for the most part, but I cannot get anything for the `responseType` property. I was expecting it to be `json` but anything would be helpful.

I thought that a suitable mime type would do the job. I have tried it in Firefox, which has generally very good support, as well as in Safari.

What am I missing?

Comment: Found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845401/xmlhttprequest-responsetype-json-giving-error-syntax-err-dom-exception-12). Looks like the responseType JSON isn't supported by all browsers

Answer (score 1):

`responseType` is not the MIMEType of the server's response. You can set it before sending the `XMLHttpRequest` in order to influence the type of the `response` attribute when the response arrives. For details see [XMLHttpRequest Level 1 at W3C.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).

You access the MIMEType of the server's response as `this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")`.

Answer (score 0):

> The Content-type header is just used as info for your application. The
>   browser doesn't care what it is. The browser just returns you the data
>   from the AJAX call. If you want to parse it as JSON, you need to do
>   that on your own.
>
> The header is there so your app can detect what data was returned and
>   how it should handle it. You need to look at the header, and if it's
>   application/json then parse it as JSON.
>
> This is actually how jQuery works. If you don't tell it what to do
>   with the result, it uses the Content-type to detect what to do with
>   it.

Found at  [HTTP Content-Type Header and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620300/http-content-type-header-and-json)